# Static file can't run succefully?

Tags: python, django

I have main.js file.

I use the static's setting(red part)

[image]

My hello_world.html use main.js file.

But it can't run succefully.

How to modify this?

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Please post the actual code instead of screenshots

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that your static root isn't set correctly.

It should be a path to the folder where your static files are.

So probably /static/

E.g.

```
STATIC_ROOT = "/home/user/django_project/static"
```

The STATIC url tag works out the real url based on the static root + the argument given (in this case 'js/main.js').

To check open the debugger in your web browser (usually ctrl + shift + 'i') and look at the network tab to see the url that is being generated for that item.

Comment: What url does the network tab show when it tries to download that file?

Comment: And did you quote the STATIC_ROOT path, I realized the first version of my answer did not.

Comment: STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
#STATIC_ROOT = '/home/leo/HackIDEtest/static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

Comment: I use these setting and that works. It have to clean the cache.Sorry my mistake.